# Story about a lonely alien inhabiting a planet that communicates telepathically

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read a book/short story in the 1980s about a lonely alien inhabiting a planet that communicates telepathically with people in a spaceship passing nearby.  I think it was a yellow-jacket VGSF (Victor Gollancz Science Fiction) book.

Comment: Is it the alien or the planet that communicates telepathically?

Comment: This is awfully vague. Are there no other plot points you can remember? Any names of characters in the story? Or names of spaceships? What happened as a result of the communication? You say _book/short story_ but the plot sounds very thin for a book.

Comment: Does the alien or the planet do the communicating?

Comment: Apologies for being so vague: the alien does the communicating.  I can't recall any names but I think the alien tries to stop them leaving the planet's orbit because it is desperate for some mental "companionship".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Time is the simplest thing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1269436.Time_Is_the_Simplest_Thing) by Clifford Simak.
Not quite the same (no traditional space travel is involved), but ticks the lonely alien, making ESP contact with "passerbys".

Short story, good read.